# AngularJS: ngChange not called from directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend

### Brief intro to my problem

I have a directive that dynamically shows a list of checkboxes. It has a parameter called `options` that should be an array like the following, in order to show the list of checkboxes correctly. For example:

```
var options = [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: 'option #1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        label: 'option #2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        label: 'option #3'
    }
];
```

So, by passing this array to my directive, a group of three checkboxes would be shown.

Also, the directive requires `ngModel` that will have the result of checking/unchecking the checkboxes (this object is always passed initialized). For example:

```
var result = {
    "1": true,
    "2": true,
    "3": false
};
```

This case means that the first and second checkboxes (options with `id=1` and `id=2`) are checked and the third (option with `id=3`) is unchecked.

#### My directive

**template.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="option in options track by $index">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   ng-model="result[option.id]">
                {{ ::option.label }}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**directive.js**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {

    var directive = {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        },
        link: linkFunc
    };

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.result;

        ngModel.$render = setResult;

        function setResult() {
            scope.result = ngModel.$viewValue;
        };

    };

};
```

### What I want to achieve

Wherever I use my directive, I want to be able to trigger a function whenever the `ngModel` changes. Of course, I would like to achieve this using `ngChange`. So far I have the following:

```
<my-directive
    name="myName"
    options="ctrlVM.options"
    ng-model="ctrlVM.result"
    ng-change="ctrlVM.selectionChanged()">
</my-directive>
```

but the `.selectionChanged()` function is not triggered whenever the model changes. Anyone has any idea why this is not working as I am expecting it to work?

Comment: where is .selectionChanged() defined ? and the controller? Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: It is defined at the controller of the view where the directive is being used. But that should not be a problem, it's always going to be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Gaurav` correctly identified the problem (`ng-change` is never called because the object reference does not change).  Here is a simpler solution that doesn't require manually cloning into the controller's model:

1. Add a binding for the `ng-change` attribute:

   ```
   scope: {
       options: '=',
       ngChange: '&'  // Add this, creates binding to `ctrlVM.selectionChanged()`
   }
   ```
2. Add an `ng-change` to your checkbox template:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox"
                ng-model="result[option.id]" ng-change="ngChange()">
   ```

Now, when any checkbox changes it will automatically call the outer `ng-change` function without the intermediate step of cloning into the model.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, please try to provide jsfiddle, codepen etc code snippet link so that it will be easy for others to answer your question.

The problem in your case is that you are never updating the `ctrlVM.result` object as you are passing the object's reference and that reference never change even if you manually update the model by calling `ngModel.$setViewValue()`.

To solve the problem, just update the model by manually calling `ngModel.$setViewValue()` and pass in the new Object so that the reference changes and that will trigger the `ngChange` directives logic.

I've added the logic to do that and it will successfully trigger the change. Look at the code below:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDirective', myDirective)
  .controller('MyController', function($timeout) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.options = [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'option #1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: 'option #2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      label: 'option #3'
    }];

    vm.result = {
      "1": true,
      "2": true,
      "3": false
    };

    vm.selectionChanged = function() {
      vm.isChanged = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        vm.isChanged = false;
      }, 500)
    }

  });

function myDirective() {

  var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      options: '='
    },
    link: linkFunc
  };

  return directive;

  function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    scope.result;

    ngModel.$render = setResult;

    function setResult() {
      scope.result = ngModel.$viewValue;
    };

    scope.updateValue = function(val) {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(Object.assign({}, val))
    }

  };

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
    <div ng-repeat="option in options track by $index">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"
                   ng-model="result[option.id]" ng-click="updateValue(result)">
                {{ ::option.label }}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrlVM">

    <my-directive name="myName" options="ctrlVM.options" ng-model="ctrlVM.result" ng-change="ctrlVM.selectionChanged()">
    </my-directive>

    <div> Data: {{ctrlVM.result}} </div>

    <div> isChanged: {{ctrlVM.isChanged}} </div>

  </div>
</div>
```